# Finding maximum of added fields

Tags: scripts, text-processing, awk

Given a text file `numbers.data`:

```
James:230:200:200
Kory:140:204:240
Hogan:293:234:100
Logan:233:444:200
```

Fields delimited by a colon, what is the simplest `awk` command to add the second, third, and fourth fields and find the maximum out of the four shown records? If possible, how to print the first field (name) of the individual with this maximum field sum?

I.e. display: `Logan 877` and store it to a variable.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
awk -F: '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) sum[$1]+=$i} END{for(j in sum) if (sum[j] > max) \
           {n=j; max=sum[j]}; print n, max}' file.txt
```

- `-F:` sets the field separator as `:`
- `{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) sum[$1]+=$i}` iterates over the fields and creates an array `sum` with the field values starting from the second added
- In the end (`END`), `for(j in sum) if (sum[j] > max) {n=j; max=sum[j]}; print n, max}` iterates over the array elements and find the maximum number and print it with the name in front

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
James:230:200:200
Kory:140:204:240
Hogan:293:234:100
Logan:233:444:200

% awk -F: '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) sum[$1]+=$i} END{for(j in sum) if (sum[j] > max) {n=j; max=sum[j]}; print n, max}' file.txt
Logan 877
```

Comment: Great answer, but could you explain what the $1 in `sum[$1]`'s purpose is?

Comment: @KMoy `sum[$1]` creates an (associative) array `sum`, with the first field's value (`$1`) as the key, and whatever follows after `=` as the value.

Comment: Thanks! I am also assuming max is a built-in function for arrays such as this?

Comment: @KMoy `max` is a variable, just to keep track of the current maximum (and use in comparison later) while iterating over the array elements.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk > 4.0, you could avoid writing an explicit max function by sorting the array and printing the first name-value pair:

```
gawk -F: '
  {a[$1]=0+$2+$3+$4} 
  END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"; for (i in a){print i,a[i]; break}}
' file
Logan 877
```